# Is <svg> allowed within <time>?

Tags: html, validation

The permitted content for [the `time` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) is "phrasing content". [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) includes the `svg` element. Yet, when I create a page that nests an `svg` within a `time` element and run it through [the W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/), it says:

> Error: Element svg not allowed as child of element time in this context.

For reference, here is a minimal example that fails validation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>svg within time test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <time>
            <svg version="1.1" class="separator" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 100">
                <g class="sep">
                    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="9.52"/>
                    <circle cx="30" cy="70" r="9.52"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </time>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hence, I am now confused on whether or not you can nest `svg` within `time`? I might just not be reading the documentation correctly, maybe?

Comment: Show us your actual HTML.

Comment: @Dai sure, I've added a minimal example.

Comment: [The HTML Specification says that a `<time>` element **must** have a `datetime=""` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) (with a valid formatted date/time for its value) if you want to add element-children. If a `<time>` element lacks a `datetime=""` attribute then the element can only contain text and not any elements - and that text must also be a correctly-formatted date/time value.

Comment: @Dai ah, yeah, I _just_ saw that exact thing and can confirm this is indeed the issue. Thank you. Feel free to make your comment into an answer - in which case I'll delete my own in favor of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out after carefully reading the MDN page on `time` again, where it says:

> The datetime value (the machine-readable value of the datetime) is the value of the element's datetime attribute, which must be in the proper format (see below). **If the element does not have a datetime attribute, it must not have any element descendants**, and the datetime value is the element's child text content.

Since my page was adding the `datetime` attribute via JavaScript, and the validator doesn't seem to be executing that JavaScript before validating the markup, it showed the error. Manually adding a `datetime` attribute just to test makes it so the markup actually passes the validation.

Comment: If you're using JS to manipulate the `<time>` element then why not omit the element in the raw SSR HTML and have JS create the `<time>` element at runtime?

Comment: That's a good idea.